# Ansible FAILED! => {"msg": "'users' is undefined"}

Tags: ansible

I try to run a task which uses extern variables from a list.
It throws me `FAILED! => {"msg": "'users' is undefined"}`
This is my task

```
---
- include_vars:
    file: /path/to/list/userCreateList.yaml
    name: item

- name: createUser and add to sudoer
  become: yes
  user:
    name: "{{ user }}"
    groups: "sudo, www-data"
    password: "{{ 'password' | password_hash('sha512', 'mysecretsalt') }}"
    update_password: on_create
    state: present
    shell: /bin/bash
    system: no
    createhome: yes
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  register: useradd

- name: change user password upon creation
  shell: chage -d 0 "{{ user.name }}"
  loop: "{{ useradd.results }}"
  when: item.changed
```

This is my userCreateList.yaml

```
users:
 - username1
```

I assume that ansible tries to loop over my list does not get username1.
How can i fix this?

Comment: I think you need to omit the `name: item` on the `include_vars`

Comment: Thank you, that brings me a step further, now its creating a user, unfortunately with a lot of brackets and quotations marks e.g.  '['\''username1'\'']'/. How can i get rid of this and can you explain me why do i have to omit `name: item`, what was the reason?

Comment: `name: "{{ user }}"` should probably be `name: "{{ item }}"` (unless you have a `loop_control` setting)

Comment: If you're getting those brackets, that means you're somehow getting the whole list rather than individual items

Comment: One useful trick for developing things like this is to replace the action with `debug` with the `var` option; then you can debug how to get all the values lined up separately from having a target system where you're creating the users; just have a little three-task playbook just to get the loop right, targeting `-i localhost,`

Comment: Ah alright, that works. Whats confusing me is that the user is successfully created but ansible throws me a very long error with all users parameters with the note at the end: `
stderr_lines: ["chage: Permission denied."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
`
But i execute the task with `-K` so with the sudo password to have permissions to create users. Can i get rid of this? And i noticed if i login with the users credentials, i dont get the option to change my password which i specified in the ansibles task

Comment: Ah my bad, forgot the privilege escalation. Now it works perfectly, thansk a lot!